# Binary - semi-major axis computation

Tags: binary-star

I tried this formula for WW Aur:

$$a(R_\mathrm{nom}) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{P(\mathrm{d})^2}{365.2564^2}[M_1(M_{\mathrm{nom}})+M_2(M_{\mathrm{nom}})]} \cdot \frac{149597870.7}{695700}$$

What is wrong, please?

```
# WW Aur test

R_sol_km = 695700
year_day = 365.2564
AU_km = 149597870.7



P = 2.52501941 # d
M1 = 1.964     # M_sol
M2 = 1.814     # M_sol
a = 12.15      # R:sol


print('a: should be:', a, 'is:', (P**2/year_day**2*(M1+M2))**(1/3)*AU_km/R_sol_km)
```

Output:

```
a: should be: 12.15 is: 0.012941299276573308
```

Comment: It's unit conversion.  You're squaring the period in days, but you're not squaring the number of years per day. As a result, the formula you're using is giving an incorrect value.

Comment: Thank you very much. And now? Is factor 1000 missing somewhere, please?

Comment: You're probably hitting an Order of operations issue with your exponentiation occurring before the division, so you need to wrap parentheses around `(1/3)`.  I also have no idea why you're multiplying the result by `AU_km/R_sol_km`

Comment: The parentheses around 1/3 give the same result. I am sorry, the result should be in solar radius; thus, I am converting the result in au to km and then to solar radius.

Comment: You aren't showing the values you are using for `year_day`, `AU_km`, or `R_sol_km` in your python code snippet. You should indeed get about 12.15 solar radii.

Comment: @notovny The questioner is trying to express the semi-major axis length of the orbit of the two components of WW Aur about one another in units of solar radii.

Comment: I added the values to my question. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running your script exactly as it is and it gives me

```
a: should be: 12.15 is: 12.153517320591716
```

Try clearing your python console and running it again, it should work!

Comment: Thank you very much